# How to connect a GWT website with an Android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-messaging

In the eclipse toolkit there are two possibilities:
1. Create New Web application project.
2. Create New App engine connected Android project.

how do i combine them both, so i can get an app engine server that's connected to a web site and can send GCM to android and receive messages back from the android?

Answer (score 0):

You would create two projects:

1. For the App Engine application
2. For the web site.

Then, you should add the necessary code in both projects to communicate among them and to Android devices.